# What is the highest upvoted/downvoted question, answer and comment on this site, and who is the highest rep user? (Writing.SE)

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, up-votes, users

I know that this question is completely useless and trivial, but I am really curious. In the post about the departure of a significant user here, I couldn't help but notice the high rep users commenting. And I remember seeing the OP with 50K and thinking "wow, that's as high as it goes", then sreing someone with above 80K. So, it has made me excruciatingly curious, who is the user with the highest reputation?

And on the same note, what question, answer and comment has been upvoted/downvoted the most? I know there was a question asked here, on meta, asking about how someone could possibly downvote their question, and that post got downvoted to oblivion. I believe someone joked "the downvotes are for the irony, right?", which was pretty hilarious. Another point of curiosity is the color change of the votes on comments. Does the tinge ever evolve from orange?

So, if you have the knowledge and you're willing to take a little time off your day to answer this completely trivial question, I'd be very happy.

Comment: As for people asking on Meta why their question was downvoted and then it gets downvoted further, that's a pretty well-recognized phenomenon, sometimes referred to as "the Meta effect". There's nothing magical about posting a link on Meta that necessarily leads to a post being downvoted, but drawing attention to a post (question *or* answer alike), which posting a link to it on Meta often does, will usually increase the number of votes cast on it. If the post is of poor quality for some reason, there will likely be downvotes cast on it. And there you have it...

Comment: @aCVn You mean to say that when people downvote a bad post there is some fuzziness that causes surrounding posts to get downvoted unintentionally as well?

Comment: @B.L.E. Depends on how one reads what OP wrote, I guess. I initially read it as the *referenced* post being downvoted, but I see how it can also be read as *the post that referenced it* being downvoted. The latter can perhaps be simply because users feel "you really should be able to figure that out without asking".

Comment: @aCVn That was indeed what I meant, referring to what you called "the Meta effect".

Answer (score 8):

You can display all [users ordered by reputation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all).

*(I'm not sure if the list of users on the [Area 51 proposal page of Writers](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1623/writers) still gets updated. I cannot find myself there, and maybe it only lists users that were members during the beta stage.)*

You can find the highest voted questions and answers by sorting search results:

- [questions sorted from highest votes to lowest](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq&tab=votes)
- [answers sorted from highest votes to lowest](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aa&tab=votes)

You can run similar queries on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE). Here is a query finding the

- [highest voted comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/writers/query/1089361/highest-voted-comments) (you'll have to wait a minute until the query results appear at the bottom of the page)

---

Comment: I had a feeling it was @Amadeus

Comment: I didn't know we could sort comments by upvotes, cool.  As for the Area 51 page, yes, it's updated.  But that is a good point that the updates may have stopped a 8 days ago.

Comment: Interestingly, the highest upvoted answer is one answering the highest upvoted question. More interesting is the fact that the question has more upvotes than the answer. Usually, after what I've experienced, it's the opposite. Perhaps questions were of higher quality back in the day. Also, 130 votes for a comment is insane.

Comment: I see. What was the whole "Me too actually" in the comment section about, and how did such a big quantity of them manage to have 23 votes?